# Smarty_Compiler.class.php Error

Tags: php

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Smarty_Compiler in /home/rainingt/public_html/quadhits/libs/Smarty-2.6.26/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 35. What does it mean?

```
/* $Id: Smarty_Compiler.class.php 3163 2009-06-17 14:39:24Z monte.ohrt $ */
    
/**
 * Template compiling class
 * @package Smarty
 */
    
class Smarty_Compiler extends Smarty {          --------------      this is line 35                  

// internal vars
/**#@+
 * @access private
 */
var $_folded_blocks         =   array();    // keeps folded template blocks
var $_current_file          =   null;       // the current template being compiled
var $_current_line_no       =   1;          // line number for error messages
var $_capture_stack         =   array();    // keeps track of nested capture buffers
var $_plugin_info           =   array();    // keeps track of plugins to load
var $_init_smarty_vars      =   false;
var $_permitted_tokens      =   array('true','false','yes','no','on','off','null');
var $_db_qstr_regexp        =   null;        // regexps are setup in the constructor
var $_si_qstr_regexp        =   null;
var $_qstr_regexp           =   null;
var $_func_regexp           =   null;
var $_reg_obj_regexp        =   null;
```

Answer (score 2):

This mean that your class was already declared somewhere else and you are trying to declare it again. Be sure to NOT include twice the same file containing this class.

A quick solution is to wrap your class within this IF statement. You should ALWAYS use that to avoid any problem similar to what you have.

```
<?php

if(class_exists('Smarty_Compiler') === FALSE){
    //  Your class here
    class Smarty_Compiler extends Smarty {

        // ...

    }
}

?>
```

or depending on your programmation markup style ...

```
<?php

if(!class_exists('Smarty_Compiler')){
    //  Your class here
    class Smarty_Compiler extends Smarty {

        // ...

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I have on idea where to add the IF statement

Comment: above line 35 and put the last `}` after the end of the class